Injecting vault secrets into Superset
I installed the Superset on a production Kubernetes cluster. I'm using an external Postgres instance. I created a schema in Postgresql using CRD and a password and user were generated in Vault.
How can I inject vault secrets to Superset?
The clue I found was adding the following to the chart:
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-pre-populate-only: 'true'
vault.hashicorp.com/role: '{{ .Values.name }}'
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-config: 'kv/{{ .Release.Namespace }}/{{ .Values.name }}'
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-config: |
  {{`{{ with secret "`}}kv/{{ .Release.Namespace }}/{{ .Values.name }}{{`" -}}`}}
    {{`{{ range $key, $value := .Data -}}
      {{ $key }}={{ $value }}{{printf "\n"}}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}`}}

and run like this:
env $(cat /vault/secrets/config) /bin/sh -c
               'START_SCRIPT'

However, I don't know where in values it should be added.
Thanks.
